# Can I use Factory Girl or some related gem without using a testing framework?

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

I don't do TDD yet, but I want to be able to create 'dummy data' in my database.

As far as I understand it, Factory Girl is a perfect gem to do this.

Looking through the docs, there seems to be a tight coupling with RSpec and other testing frameworks.

Can I use Factory Girl to populate dummy data without needing to write tests?

Thanks.

Comment: Upvoted the question & answer, IMO its a perfectly valid question. Who ever downvoted the question should explain why he feels otherwise.

Comment: Thanks @Ck- Didn't even realize it got downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. Just include `factory_girl_rails` outside your test group in your Gemfile, and then you can happily use it anywhere.

I wouldn't recommend using it in your app outside development or test, though.

Comment: Hrmm...that's a good idea. I am thinking of using it just in development, but I would love to generate fake data for my client to see the app populated.

Comment: You'll probably need to tell it where to find your factory definitions.  By default, it only looks in spec/factories or test/factories.  Something like `FactoryGirl.definition_file_paths = ['factories']; FactoryGirl.find_definitions`.

Comment: Can `factory_girl` also generate 'dummy images'? As in, say each user needs to have a banner image & avatar. Can it do that? If not, what can I use to generate dummy images also?

Comment: @marcamillion You could use an external service like lorempixel, placekitten or placehold.it; or just have a selection of images on your PC and select random ones.